# High order (up to 4) derivatives of Chebyshev polynomials needed

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials

I need to compute high order (up to 4) derivatives of Chebyshev polynomials at the points of the Chebyshev-Lobato grid:

$$x_j=cos(πj/N), j=0,\dots,N$$

Does anyone know how to do that? I tried iterative methods but too clumsy. I also made an attempt to use the differential equation but didn't work either.

The polynomials can be defined by

$$T_n(\cos(\theta))=\cos(n\theta)$$

and I can differentiate wrt $\theta$ and use the chain rule for the first derivative but this doesn't generalize to higher derivatives. I remember seeing something like that in an old paper but now it's nowhere to be found.

Any help appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Are you really asking how to find derivatives of a single variable polynomial?

Comment: There are at least two kinds of Chebyshv polynomials. Are you using the polynomials given by $T_n(x) = \cos(n\theta)$ where $\theta =  \arccos(x)$?

Comment: I suspect that you are differentiating with respect to $x$ (harder) and not $\theta$ (easy), but you should also add this information to your question.

Comment: Yes I am interested in $T_n(x)$. Also, differentiating with respect to x. The first derivative is related to the other polynomials, $U_n(x)$ but how to continue to higher-order derivatives?

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica gets it via `(x^2 - 1)^3*D[ChebyshevT[n, x], {x, 4}] // FullSimplify`:

$
n \left(n \left(-n^2+3 (n-3)^2 x^2+4\right) U_{n-4}(x)+(n-3) x \left(3 n \left(n-2 (n-3) x^2\right) U_{n-3}(x)+(n-1) \left((n-2) x^2-3\right) U_{n-1}(x)\right)\right)
$

Next you can evaluate at your desired points:

```
f[x_] := D[ChebyshevT[n, x], {x, 4}]
FullSimplify[f[Cos[j*\[Pi]/n]], 
 Assumptions -> {j \[Element] Integers, n \[Element] Integers}]
```

to get

$$
T_{n}^{(4)}(\cos(j\pi/n)) = (-1)^j n^2 \csc^4(\pi j/n) (-15 \csc^2(\pi j/n)+n^2+11)
$$